# fields with dynamic values

Tags: odoo

I'm developping a new module and I have a small question. 
In the purchase orders, I added two fields : project_id and phase_id, who respectively associate the PO to a project and a project phase. The thing is, once the project is chosen, the phase field still displays all the phases existing in the database. Is there a way to display only the phases from the chosen project? Maybe with on_change ? But I'm new to OpenERP development and I have no clue how to use it...

Thank you in advance.

PS : By the way, I'm using the 6.1 version if it changes anything to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use domain condition in the xml for the field phase_id

```
<field name="project_id"/>
<field name="phase_id" domain="[('project_id','=',project_id)]"/>
```

this will solve your problem

Comment: I've just tried it but I get : ValueError: Invalid field 'associated_project' in domain expression [('associated_project', '=', 6)]

Comment: what is this 'associated_project'? is that a field in phase? and is that field related to project.project model?

Comment: associated_project is the real name of my project_id. I just forgot to change the error message sorry :(

Comment: @user1652066: Can please you provide some more information about your code?

Comment: In purchase order if you have defined two field as associated_project and phase_id, then in xml <field name="phase_id" domain="[('project_id','=',associated_project)]">